# Jest: Wait for an async test to finish before running the next one

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, jestjs, supertest

Assuming I have these test cases (with `jest` and `supertest`):

```
describe('Test actors', async () => {
  const params = { /* ... */ }
  let actorId

  test(`Create an actor ${actorsUrl}`, async () => {
    const response = await request(app.callback())
      .post(actorsUrl)
      .send(params)
      .set('Accept', 'application/json')
      .set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
      .expect(200)
    expect(response.body.name).toBe(params.name)
    expect(response.body.address).toBe(params.address)
    actorId = response.body.id
  })

  test(`Get the actor created ${actorsUrl}/${actorsUrl}`, async () => {
    const response = await request(app.callback())
      .get(`${actorsUrl}/${actorsUrl}`)
      .set('Accept', 'application/json')
      .expect(200)
    expect(response.body.name).toBe(params.name)
    expect(response.body.address).toBe(params.address)
  })
})
```

I want to wait for first test to finish before running the second one (because the first one creates a `Actor` and the second one ask the API for the created `Actor`). Running this code fails because the actor is not already created.

Is there a way to wait for the first test to finish before calling the second one?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[jestjs](/questions/tagged/jestjs) is just a wrapper over [jasmine](/questions/tagged/jasmine), and in many cases it relies on `jasmine`'s rules.

Therefore, you can make use of [the same `done` callback](https://jasmine.github.io/tutorials/async) that is passed to the `test` function:

```
test(`Create an actor ${actorsUrl}`, async (done) => {
    const response = await request(app.callback())
      .post(actorsUrl)
      .send(params)
      .set('Accept', 'application/json')
      .set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
      .expect(200)
    expect(response.body.name).toBe(params.name)
    expect(response.body.address).toBe(params.address)
    actorId = response.body.id
    done();
})
test(`Get the actor created ${actorsUrl}/${actorsUrl}`, async (done) => {
    const response = await request(app.callback())
      .get(`${actorsUrl}/${actorsUrl}`)
      .set('Accept', 'application/json')
      .expect(200)
    expect(response.body.name).toBe(params.name)
    expect(response.body.address).toBe(params.address)
    done();
})
```

You can read more about that in jest's [async documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/asynchronous)